# In flutter firebase cloud messaging is not working in oneplus 6/6t in production

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, oneplus6t

In debug mode firebase cloud messaging is working fine in all phones but in production its not working in oneplus phones but its working fine in samsung phones. Battery optimization is not the issue,

I have seen solutions like setting channel id etc... if it is the solution can u please guide me with the solution in dart.

I am new to flutter ,and now stuck with this bug

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.5 19F101, locale en-IN) • Flutter version 1.17.5 at /users/rohitmadhu/Documents/flutter • Framework revision 8af6b2f038 (2 weeks ago), 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700 • Engine revision ee76268252 • Dart version 2.8.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2) • Android SDK at /Users/rohitmadhu/Library/Android/sdk • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2 • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405) • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5) • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer • Xcode 11.5, Build version 11E608c • CocoaPods version 1.9.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5) • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents • Flutter plugin version 44.0.1 • Dart plugin version 191.8593 • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.47.0) • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents • Flutter extension version 3.12.2

[✓] Connected device (1 available) • Rohit • 2d314272e0c5e22659a0de1a57d7ccc8915fc944 • ios • iOS 13.5.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this solution is correct or not but it worked for me

Once you update SHA-1 in firebase in some devices we need uninstall the app and need to reinstall, just updating new version from play store was causing this issue.

thank you for all who spend time for this question.